# How to retrieve a list of registered geofences from Google Play services?

Tags: android, geofencing, android-geofence

I am building an app that can easily access all the resources used by other apps. For that I require a list of all the registered geofences in the play services of a particular device ? Is there a particular way to do this ?

Comment: `I am building an app that can easily access all the resources used by other apps.` ??? Why do you want to access the resources of my apps?